# Can't load project due to iis express configuration/file missing

Tags: iis, iis-7

I can't load the project in visual studio 2013.

error  : The Web project 'ProjectName' is configured to use IIS Express. You must download and install IIS Express in order to load this project.

has any simple solution for this?

Comment: "You must download and install IIS Express in order to load this project." Can't get simpler than that !

Comment: Thanks for your answer.it doesn't work.i have setup my windows again.that's why it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a project on VS2015.

I deleted all the files in the repository (using Windows Explorer), then pulled the branch again, discarding all changes. This solved the issue, so I think this might have been down to some configuration file in the bin or something.